# How to change time to zero for all column values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column for dates with different time values in the format (MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM). I want to change the time values to zero for the entire column without changing the date value. Meaning the result would be (MM/DD/YYYY 00:00:00 AM/PM). For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeGyX.png) becomes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M4Fh.png)

I had previously done this in an extremely simple way but now I have forgotten how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would like to suggest one tricky method to set the Time to ZERO, in **Date TimeStamp** Cell/Range of Cells.*

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Select the Date range that you want to set Zero for the Time.
2. From **Home** Tab, Click **Find & Replace**.
3. Now enter **a Space** and an asterisk `*` into the **Find what** box. And keep the **Replace with** box blank.
4. Click either **Replace/Replace All**.

*Excel converts the Time part into ZERO in Date TimeStamp Cell/Cells.*

**N.B.**

1. Actually Excel sets the Date TimeStamp to,  `06/22/2019  12:00:00 AM`, which reflects like `06/22/19 0:00` into the Cell.
2. In fact the Time part is still active as Time, if you apply this Formula `=TIME(HOUR(E31)+1,MINUTE(E31),SECOND(E31))` in Cell `F31`, you get `1:00 AM`.

**Therefore the shown method can be used to set ZERO for display purpose only.**

Comment: 1. OK, learned something cool and new.  Do you know what that actually does?  It appears that space+wildcard finds the space between the date and time, even though that is only formatting, and deletes the space and everything after it (the time).  Except that it doesn't delete it in the formatted output; it knows that the time is the decimal portion and deletes that in the stored number.  The display continues to show a placeholder for the time because it still has that formatting.  2. I don't have ready access to Excel.  (cont'd)

Comment: From your image, I see that time gets displayed as 0:00.  I tried it in WPS Office, which is extremely compatible, but while that does chop off the time, it displays it as it normally would for a date/time with a time of zero (12:00 AM).  LibreOffice wouldn't replicate the trick at all (no change from the find/replace).  But you demonstrated that this works in Excel, so +1.  3. Congrats on passing 5K.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234, yes this one is tricky so that I've mentioned all as caveat (N.B), I've never tried it for other than Excel 2013 & 1216,, so difficult to rule out the possibility,,, Thanks again ☺

Comment: Glad to help you @Bob ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking to to just display the date information then you can use the short date format which basically hides the time portion.

If you want to create a formula in another column, remember that in excel the digits represent the date and the decimals represent time, so something like `=int(a1)` in the cell b1 would give you the date as a number, then use the short date or date/time format to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Excel stores date & time values as floating point values where the integer portion is the date and the fraction is the time. To get the date-only value, use the trunc function to drop the fractional part.